# looping rep function with unequal groups

Tags: r

First time poster on this site but a frequent visitor.

I have a dataset containing say 50 individual animals. Each animal has 400-700 locations. I'm attempting to separate 8 consecutive steps per individual (e.g., steps 1-8, 9-16, 17-24, and so on) for some analysis. So I'm trying to add a new column to the dataframe that identifies groups of steps by individuals (steps 1-8 would be 1, steps 9-16, would be 2...) which will eventually be merged with animal ID.

I'm attempting to loop the replicate function to get this information.  Something like this:

```
for (i in unique (pathdf$id)){
  n<-rep(1:700,each=8,length.out=348644)
  pathdf$newcolumn[i]<-n
}
```

Unfortunately, the individual groups do not always have row numbers that are equal to 8. I've tried different approaches to remedy the issue but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for `findInterval`, but it would be helpful if you posted some sample input data and the corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether the steps are created after ordering based on `locations` within each `id`.  If that is the case, first the dataset is ordered and then create the `steps` using `ave`

```
pathdf1 <- pathdf[with(pathdf, order(id, locations)),]
row.names(pathdf1) <- NULL
pathdf1 <- within(pathdf1, steps <- ave(id, id,
                FUN=function(x) (seq_along(x)-1)%/%8 +1))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
pathdf2 <- pathdf1 %>% 
                  group_by(id) %>% 
                  mutate(steps1 =rep(1:ceiling(n()/8), each=8, 
                                               length.out=n()))

all.equal(pathdf2$steps, pathdf2$steps1)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(49)
pathdf <- data.frame(id=sample(1:20,20*40,replace=TRUE), 
                         locations=sample(20*40))
```

Comment: To answer your previous question, locations for each animal id were ordered by date (GPS radio-telemetry data).